# Jaspersoft studio can't display dataset (connection working properly)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jasper-reports

I am trying to create a simple report with Jaspersoft studio 5.5.0 from a MySql db. I can set up connection to the database and `Test connection` reports `successful`. but when I try to actually bind data from mysql db to report and design query, no tables are shown. I tried adding jdbc driver to project build path. But it didn't work (maybe I was doing something wrong).

Comment: Did you test connection string in another application (or Java code)?

Comment: Yes, and it works. It even works in jasper studio database adapter creation dialog(I tried connecting to other Mysql databases on the server and all of them showed success). But when I try to build queries, I see an empty page and tables are not retrieved from db.

Comment: Here is a picture of the dialog box I am referring to:

http://community-static.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/questions/problem_0.jpg